# Exception has occurred. FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) <HTML></HTML> ^ )

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a news application, and I get my data by JSON and in each running my app get me a crash on (`response HTTP`) I can't understand it:

> `Exception has occurred. FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1
>   <HTML></HTML> ^ )`

**Code:**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Category {

  int id;
  String title;

  Category({ 
    this.id,
    this.title 
  });

  static Future<List<Category>> getCategories() async {

    http.Response response = await http.get("url JSON"); // <- Here carash

    Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);

    List<Category> list = [];

    for(var map in map['categories']){
      list.add(
        Category(id: map['id'], title: map['title'])
      );
    }
    return list;
  }

}
```

Comment: are you sure your JSON URL returns JSON, not HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing something wrong with request I think and the api does not handle that error and throws the error as html as I guess. Anyway, the way you are decoding is not the proper way.

Few points to keep in mind when you are doing http request:

- Most importantly study data type (HTML / JSON) and structure of the
  data. By printing to the console or great way to use curl request or postman.
- Always make sure to wrap your `json.decode()` with a `try - catch`
  block, When there is a error, you can properly see what's going on
  with your code.
- Make sure that your response status code is 200. And handle your data occordingly.
- And before iterate over the decoded response, ensure that it contains
  value.
- If you don't know the type or if you are not
  sure, without using static type to assign decoded response body use
  `final` (Dont always use dynamic type, my suggestion for only for situations like this). This will help you with `FormatException` like the situation you are facing.
- Last but not least, when you want to check error messages with status code. As example,
  when checking `expired jwt`,    you are getting `500` as status code.
  So only checking status code is    not enough in that situation
  because of `500` means `internal server error`.

Ex:
List list = [];

```
try {
    final decodedBody = json.decode(response.body); // when you have error messages with response, you can also check message with status code

    debugPrint(decodedBody?.toString());

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        if (decodedBody != null && map['categories'] != null) { // you can also check the data type you want here ex: (map is List)
            for(var map in map['categories']){
              list.add(Category(id: map['id'], title: map['title']));
            }

            // Below is another thrilled way to do this

            // list = decodedBody.map['categories']((item) => Category(id: item['id'], title: item['title'])).toList();
        }
    }

} catch(e, _) {
    debugPrint(e.toString());
}
```

Wish this helpful. Follow above steps and if there any other error let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The response that you are receiving is not a JSON and so your JSON can't be decoded.

Your server is returning some HTML tags and this means you might be requesting to the wrong URL, please check the URL in PostMan or Browser and see response.